# Oracle JDBC ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType returns wrong value

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In my Oracle table I have a few FLOAT columns, and a bunch of NUMBER columns.

But, for all of those columns, [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int)) method returns 2, which is [`java.sql.Types.NUMERIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.NUMERIC).

I am trying to find out why is it not returning 6 for [`java.sql.Types.FLOAT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.FLOAT) or 7 for [`java.sql.Types.REAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.REAL) or even 8 for [`java.sql.Types.DOUBLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.DOUBLE), as one would expect?

The [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType(int)) method claims to return a [`java.sql.Types`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types) value, and it obviously does not. If the column data type is FLOAT, it should then return 6 or at the very least 7 or 8.

What's the point of that method if it returns 2 for every numeric subtype?

Basically, how can one find out that the column is of type FLOAT? Is this even possible with Oracle?

**EDIT:** Wow, *everything* is an oracle.sql.NUMBER: https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/java.815/a64685/basic3.htm
:(

Comment: my guess: Float is a subtype of Numeric

Comment: Right, but then what is the point of java.sql.Types if they are not useful? :(

Comment: Why does this matter?  Doesn't JDBC provide an interface to get the Java type you want, freeing you from worrying about how the database stored or returned the value?

Comment: The ResultSetMetaData.getColumnType method claims to return a java.sql.Types value, and it does not. If the data type is FLOAT, it should return 6 or at the very least 7 or 8. What's the point of that method if it returns 2 for every numeric subtype?

Comment: And it matters because I am trying to migrate from Oracle to another database where this data type distinction is rather important.

Comment: I understand your question after the last sentence +1.  Oddly, float in Oracle should be mapping to float in JDBC.

Comment: I will add that in the question above to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it possible that somehow those Oracle columns are being cast to numeric on the database side before hitting JDBC?  In other words, perhaps JDBC is not the culprit here.

Comment: At this point, I actually fear that it is not only possible, but very likely :(

Comment: Do this: Cast those columns to float at the highest point in your query.  Check first on the database to make sure it's working.

Comment: I'm actually parsing 200+ tables using a very old Java app, in order to extract the column names and data types to then automate creation of sailsjs ORM models for a new app...

Comment: IMHO there is nothing like real float in Oracle. The only type is NUMBER, which can have up to 38 valid digits. The real corresponding Java type for NUMBER is BigDecimal. Having own numeric datatype guarantees that you will get the same results on any HW platform. Moreover you want to prevent  situations, where you store a float number in a database, but then some slightly different number is withdrawn.

Comment: PS: you practically never do any math, with "numbers" withdrawn from database. So there is no reason to convert them into "int" or "float". You might get nasty exceptions when you try to convert Oracle NUMBER into int, simply because int's precision is not big enought.